# Joining 4 tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables
Products, Products_Location, Stores, Locations

```
Products = [Product_ID, P_Name, Price]
Products_Location = [Location_ID,Product_ID]
Locations = [Location_ID,Stores_ID, L_Name]
Stores = [Stores_ID, S_Name]
```

I'm trying to show columns from each table in 1 table but its not working
I tried to use inner join twice but didnt work (it work if I use 1 inner join)
here's my code

```
"SELECT Products.P_Name, Products.Price, Stores.S_Name, Locations.L_Name, Products.Product_ID 
    From Products, Locations
    INNER JOIN Stores ON Locations.Stores_ID = Stores.Stores_ID 
    INNER JOIN Products_Location ON Products.Product_ID = Products_Location.Product_ID
    Where P_Name LIKE '%$search%' OR Price LIKE '%$search%' OR S_Name LIKE '%$search%' OR L_Name LIKE '%$search%'
    ORDER BY Price ASC";
```

Comment: Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: so I remove locations from FROM and just add another inner join for it? @GordonLinoff

Comment: Definitely. Please write all the query with standard JOINS

Comment: @Sergey I just tried to do it it didnt work

Comment: Can someone provide an argument for using INNER JOINS, instead of comma's in the FROM part, that is not just an opinion, but actually makes sense? (For instance: JOIN's give you more control over the type of join that is performed.)

Comment: @KIKO Software  'If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears you are relatively new to SQL, instead of getting pounded on your new posts, let me help a bit.  Writing your queries with JOINS (left, right, full, outer, etc) are all typically based on TableA some join to TableB.  So, try to think of your tables in a mental image.  What is the relationship between them.  THAT is the join.  If one table is joined to multiple, then treat that as its own JOIN.  I typically try to indent showing the level where TableA joins to TableB (or TableC, D, E, etc).

Then, also you can get used to using "alias" names so you dont have to keep writing LONG table name references.  Taking your original query, it would be something more like...

```
select
      p.p_name,
      p.price,
      s.s_name,
      l.l_name,
      p.product_id
   From 
      Products p
         -- first get the JOIN from product to its locations where available
         JOIN Products_Location pl
            on p.product_id = pl.product_id
            -- now, from the product location to the location table.
            -- notice my indentation to show its under the product_location
            -- and not directly from the product table.  Visually seeing the
            -- hierarchical chain can help writing queries.
            JOIN Locations l
               on pl.location_id = l.location_id
               -- and now, indent once more from location to the stores
               JOIN Stores s
                  on l.stores_id = s.stores_id
   where
      -- NOW, you can put in your filtering criteria.  But if ever a left or right
      -- based join, you would just add that part of the criteria directly within 
      -- the JOIN portion
          p.p_name like '%$search%' 
      OR  p.Price LIKE '%$search%' 
      OR  s.S_Name LIKE '%$search%' 
      OR  l.L_Name LIKE '%$search%'
   ORDER BY 
      p.Price ASC
```

Also, always try to qualify all columns in your query with table.column or alias.column so others know which table(s) the columns come from to prevent any ambiguity in the call.

Comment: it worked! I didnt know I can use shortcuts too thank you so much for your time I really appreciate that

Comment: @Amani, glad it worked, but more importantly, did you LEARN the how and WHY it worked.  The better you are at understanding, the better you will be in the future about otherwise simple join conditions even if your database has 50+ related tables .  Look only at how do I get from A -> B -> C and throw away all the other confusing parts that may have no bearing on the subject / query at hand.

Comment: yes I read your comments in the code carefully and I learned a lot from it

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a cross join on Products and Locations. Is it not your aim to instead join Products and Locations via the Products_Location table on Products.Product_ID = Products_Location.Product_ID and Products_Location.Location_ID = Locations.Location_ID?

Comment: yes I'm trying to do so through joins but its not working

Comment: Then join the tables in the following sequence: Products, Products_Location, Locations, Stores